# SharePoint form made with InfoPath and attaching picture/snippet control

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

is there a way Out of the Box that I can allow an user to attach a snippet or picture to an InfoPath 2013 form? This form is linked to a custom list in SharePoint 2013. Any help or alternatives will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create web service data connection.
Please follow this video tutorial for better understanding

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2011/11/infopath-upload-images-sharepoint-2010-no-code/

Comment: Thanks, how can I find the imagining web service url?